# Why Python can not recognize Arabic characters?

Tags: python, string, list, printing, arabic

I have a simple code. when I use English character it works perfectly but when I use Arabic characters,it seems it don't recognize it.
when I type : "hello" it returns English 
but when I type "سلام" nothing happens.

```
x = input("please enter something: ")


if x == "سلام" :
  print("Arabic")

elif x == "hello" :

  print("English")
```

Comment: What do you get if you `print(repr(x), x)`?

Comment: Which OS are You using? Windows has a pour support of utf-8. Only recent versions can.

Answer (score 3):

What Python version are you using? In Python2.7 you should type encoding declaration: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the first line of the python file.

Running this code in Python2.7 results in error message `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd8' in file...`.

After adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the first line, I get output: `Arabic`.

In Python3.6.5 I get the output `Arabic`, without adding the encoding declaration in the first line.

Try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

x = input("please enter something: ")


if x == "سلام" :
    print("Arabic")

elif x == "hello" :
    print("English")
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Python? If these are Unicode characters Python 3 should be able to handle them just fine, but in Python 2 you have to specify an encoding

Answer (score 1):

Python compiler directly can't parse UTF-8 characters, Any Latin symbol or such can't be handled directly by this compiler.

Solution- Please use translator to parse UTF-8 and to make understandable by compiler.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
x = translator.translate(input("please enter something: "))
if x.text == "سلام":
    print("Arabic")

elif x.text == "hello":
    print("English")

elif x.text == "Hello":
    print("Translated")
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `coding: utf-8` in my code and letter "u" before my texts and it worked perfectly.

```
x = input("please enter something: ")
if x == u'سلام' :
  print("Arabic")
elif x == "hello" :
  print("English")
```